# cordova-res returns Error: pngload_buffer : non-recoverable state

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, vips

I'm trying to generate the resources for an ionic app.
The *cordova-res* command returns an error.

Here what is returns with the --verbose option.

```
  cordova-res Caught fatal error: [Error: pngload_buffer: non-recoverable state
  cordova-res pngload_buffer: non-recoverable state
  cordova-res pngload_buffer: non-recoverable state
  cordova-res pngload_buffer: non-recoverable state
  cordova-res vips2png: unable to write to target target
  cordova-res ] +361ms
Error: pngload_buffer: non-recoverable state
pngload_buffer: non-recoverable state
pngload_buffer: non-recoverable state
pngload_buffer: non-recoverable state
vips2png: unable to write to target target
```

What could be wrong ?

Comment: That's a message from libspng triggered by a corrupt or malformed PNG file. The latest versions of libspng and libvips handle bad files more gracefully, I would try updating.

Comment: @jcupitt I confirm, it was the issue.